# Angular 4 routerLink loading wrong component

Tags: angular, routes

this is my app-routing.module.ts :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MainComponent, children:[
    {path: '', component: AppComponent, children:[
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    ]},
    {path: 'patient', component: PatientComponent, children: [
        { path: 'patient/profile', component: PatientProfileComponent, outlet: 'patient-outl'},
        { path: 'patient/changepass', component: ChangePasswordComponent, outlet: 'patient-outl'}
        ],
        canActivate: [RoleGuard],
        data: { roles: ['PATIENT'] }
    },
    {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: { roles: ['ADMIN'] }},
    {path: 'dentist', component: DentistComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: { roles: ['DENTIST'] }},
    {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
  ]}
];
```

I navigate from  click in patient component to changepass like so:

```
<a routerLink="/patient/changepass" routerLinkActive="active">Change Password</a>
```

but what actually opens up is HomeComponent and not ChangePasswordComponent. The url is correct - /patient/changepass, but the loaded component is wrong.. Any idea why so?

EDIT:

I also tried to navigate like so:

```
<a (click)="editProfile()">Edit Profile</a>
```

and:

```
   editProfile(){
     this.router.navigate(['/patient/profile']);
   }
```

but with the same result - navigation to home component..

Answer (score 0):

Your child routes are wrong. 
They should be relative to their parent route. Even so the named router outlet not works with non-empty paths. It seems that your issue is related with [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16406).

I prepared a working [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjz6nr)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly this did not fix my problem.. HomeComponent still opens instead of according component

Comment: where is located named router-outlet 'patient-outl'? Is it in the PatientComponent?

Comment: yes it is: like so : <div class="patient-container"> ....
  <div class="wrapper">
    <router-outlet name="patient-outl"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Thanks again bro, it works now, but only for the first child route you click on.. Then if I want to navigate to the other one, it doesn't work.. I guess this workround works only for one route..